# Rewrite GET array with Apache2 mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have URLS like this on a page of my website:

```
products/?stores[]=4812&stores[]=4797&categories[]=108&min_price=&max_price=&sort=&q=&limit=10&skip=0
```

I would like to have something nicer, like:

```
products/stores/4812,4797/categories/108/min_price//...
```

Or even uglier. The important thing is removing the troublesome square brackets and changing as little as possible server-side (I use PHP).

I tried different rules with little luck. Hints?

Comment: What rules did you try?

Comment: you're not going to be able to do that very easily with mod_rewrite. regexes are powerful, but not omnicient...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule stores/([\d,]+)/categories/([\d,]+)/min_price/([\d,]+)/sort/([\w\.]+)/ ?stores=$1&categories$2&min_price=$3&sort=$4 #etc
```

That would require you to split multiple values into an array using `explode()` though. Like so:

```
<?php
$_GET['stores'] = explode(',', $_GET['stores']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to your input, I solved it without editing my rewrite rules. I simply changed the javascript that created the URL. Still, I'm very curious if that could be done with a dynamic url, where stores and categories could be inverted and more field could be present.